# Invalid column type: getInt not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

i want to post data in oracle database 11g and i enter the data using input field the the data enter to data base but just id coulmn and another string coulmn are get correct data but another coulmn get null or 0 so i can not resolve this problem and in run time i have this error

`Invalid column type: getInt not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor`

this is my code

```
    public Client newClient(Client client){
    try {
        con = DBConnection.getConnection(driver, url, name, pass);      
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CLIENT (CID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CAREER, CSALARY) VALUES (CLIENT_ID.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        pstmt.setString(1, client.getFirstName());
        pstmt.setString(2, client.getLastName());
        pstmt.setString(3, client.getCareer());
        pstmt.setInt(4, client.getcSalary());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();      
        rs = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
         rs.next();
       Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
            client.setcId(id);          
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }finally{
        try{ rs.close(); }catch (Exception e){}
        try{ pstmt.close();}catch (Exception e){}
        try{ con.close();}catch (Exception e){}
    }//finally
    return client;
}
```

}

```
@XmlRootElement
    public class Client {
private Integer cId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String career;
private int cSalary;
public Integer getcId() {
    return cId;
}
public void setcId(Integer cId) {
    this.cId = cId;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getCareer() {
    return career;
}
public void setCareer(String career) {
    this.career = career;
}
public int getcSalary() {
    return cSalary;
}
public void setcSalary(int cSalary) {
    this.cSalary = cSalary;
}
```

}

and this is my SQL

```
  CREATE TABLE "AHMAD"."CLIENT" 
  ( "CID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"FIRSTNAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
"LASTNAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
"CAREER" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
"CSALARY" NUMBER, 
 CONSTRAINT "CLIENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CID")
   USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT        CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
   TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
     PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
         PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE            DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
         TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

plz help me the data is insert into table but not completly and i have this run time error

```
             java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: getInt not implemented for   class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CRowidAccessor
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.unimpl(Accessor.java:358)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor.getInt(Accessor.java:468)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleReturnResultSet.getInt(OracleReturnResultSet.java:265)
at com.rest.client.ClientDAO.newClient(ClientDAO.java:99)
at com.rest.client.ClientResourcs.newClient(ClientResourcs.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.jav a:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 21):

Like Mark suggested, I just faced the same problem and found the solution:

```
String generatedColumns[] = { "ID" };
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query, generatedColumns);
```

And after you execute the query, do the following to fetch the inserted ID.

```
rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
rs.next();
rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was getting this error for sometime, but never needed to use any id after a insert.. but now I had the need and the problem had to be solved! Note: Why the oracle is so outdated??!

Answer (score 9):

The Oracle JDBC driver does not return the generated id when using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` so the first column of the generated keys `ResultSet` is **not an `int`**, instead it returns a `ROWID` (see the [JDBC tutorial on rowids](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlrowid.html)) of the inserted row (so you can query the row yourself). As far as I know the reason for this is that Oracle does not have an identity type, so it doesn't actually know which field is the generated key.

Instead you should be able to explicitly specify the column you want returned using [`prepareStatement(String sql, int[] columnIndexes)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int%5B%5D%29) or [`prepareStatement(String sql, String[] columnNames)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: the data insert into table and the id is auto increment but the whole row is like that  1003 null null Dev 0  so forgive me iam beginner and have the error

Comment: Read my answer again. The problem is that you think the first column of getGeneratedKeys contains the value of the `CID` column of the inserted row, but it doesn't. It contains the rowid, which is a special pseudocolumn defined by Oracle.

Comment: prepareStatement(String sql, int[] columnIndexes) works for Oracle 11g

Comment: @AchJ You are right, and I have used `prepareStatement(String sql, String[] columnNames)` recently on Oracle, so I have removed that caveat.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know whether this issue is resoled or not but i faced same issue and it got resolved by replacing **Integer** with **int** in entity class(in your case it is **Client** class)